# Is DOM manipulation asynchronous (when using the API provided by the browsers like getElementById or appendChild)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

This bugs me. I just watched Philip Roberts's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) about the event loop and got an understanding of how the API calls will eventually put callbacks in the callback queue. But he only mentioned the XMLHtppRequest and the time out functions. What about DOM API (document.getElementById, document.appendChild)? Does they make the same effect?

Comment: _Is DOM manipulation asynchronous (when using the API provided by the browsers like getElementById or appendChild)?_ I don't think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't do any long-running stuff in the background that would require notifying you when it is ready. They directly manipulate the DOM tree. You can also infer this from the fact that there are no callbacks involved.

Comment: But isn't the DOM is still a external source from the Javascript context? Hence we need to use API to communicate with it? Unless the DOM is represented in an object which I can print out to the console (which i dont think so), then it must be an external source just like the server. You say because manipulating DOM is fast hence it doesn't need to notify me when it done and is synchronous really don't justify me. Care to explain some more?

Comment: Yes, we use an API, but it's a synchronous API (chosen because it is fast): you call into it, it returns a value, it does not use the event loop. Yes, the API is represented in a JS object that you can log out to the console: `document`. (Btw, `console.log` for example is just another API).

Comment: Thanks a  lot :D When u said synchronous API it really shed light on my brain haha. The API is the browser's implementation of course they can make it synchronous as they like.

Answer (score 7):

DOM manipulation is synchronous, however, the browser's re-rendering of the page in response to a DOM update is asynchronous. This can give the *illusion* of an asynchronous DOM update.

Comment: If I have created an element and append it to DOM, is there any way for me to do sth after this element has been appended(eg. call a function which use this element as an condition). Thank you very much.